# How can I show a user files and folders on a shared drive that are created by another user and with my app?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client, google-drive-shared-drive

I have the problem, that I can't show my users files created with my app on a shared drive, but created by other users. This destroys the collaboration possibilities. The scope I have registered is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file.

Is there any way to read files that are on a shared drive without the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope? I really would dislike using this scope.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of using an [Application data folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/appdata#application_data_folder_scope)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But how could that help me?

Comment: Because you can use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` for all the files inside it, without the need to use the full drive scope.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But how could different users access these files?